# Add whitespace to SVG via CSS to have space for CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I have an SVG and I want to slightly animate some paths via CSS. Problem is once I move around an SVG path with some `transform` it gets cropped due to overflow. So I need to increase the viewbox of the SVG prior the animation so there's extra space available.

Is there a way to do this via CSS? If not and I have to use JS, is there a generic way to reset the attribute without messing with the SVG itself? moving it, changing size etc.

Thanks!

Comment: a viewBox is an attribute and CSS can't change attribute values.

Comment: and if you increase the viewBox and not its container the SVG will be scaled down.